# How to use Jodit in a form

Tags: javascript, jodit

I am trying to use Jodit in a form, but when I save my form, it only saves the characters rather than all of the HTML in the database. I was using Quill, and I found a solution. But because I have difficulties with images with the Quill, I am trying Jodit.

I am using version `3.2.44`.

```
<textarea id="editor" name="text">${text}</textarea>
```

```
var editor = new Jodit("#editor", {
    "spellcheck": false,
    "toolbarSticky": false,
    "showWordsCounter": false,
    "buttons": "|,bold,underline,italic,|,superscript,subscript,|,ul,ol,|,outdent,indent,|,font,fontsize,brush,paragraph,|,image,table,link,|,align,undo,redo,\n,cut,hr,eraser,|,symbol,selectall,print"
});
```

I would like to know if someone can give me some example or tips. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, i was wrong. Jodit works perfectly in a form, and saving the form with the textarea my database was correctly update. I forgot that I used a sanitize, it was deleting all the tags! I only need to adjust the sanitize.